# Discord JS Module Export Visual Studio Code Completion / Suggestions

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js, nodes

I can't seem to find if it's possible to get Code Completion / Suggestions in seperate `module.exports` files if that makes any sense.

For example in my main js file:

[Shows code suggestions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/npJv3.png)

And in my messageCreate.js file:

[Doesn't show code suggestions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QJxGP.png)

Answer (score 0):

Well in client event the Code Completion knows that you have a Discord message, in the second picture it doesn't, there it just knows it has a parameter called message. If you would use TypeScript, you would get Code Completion in the module.exports too I believe.